# shmctl and semctl do not remove the ipc

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, semaphore

I am creating shared memory segments and semaphores to lock and unlock them and At the end of my program they are not removed. The code I have for removing them is as follows

```
if ((shmdt(shared_memory)) == -1) 

     fprintf(stderr, "shmdt failed\n");

if ((shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0) )== -1) 

     fprintf(stderr, "shmctl(IPC_RMID) failed\n");
```

and for the semaphore

```
    if((semctl(sid, 0, IPC_RMID, 0))==-1)

 fprintf(stderr, "semctl(IPC_RMID) failed\n");
```

None of them is getting inside the if statement which means they do not return `-1`. 
But after I run `ipcs` in my terminal they are still there with a proper key (the one that I set in my code).

Also something I have noticed is that  `shmid` right after creating and attaching to the shared memory segment is 0. Why is that? Everything is working fine in my code except removing the ipcs.

Now I know that for the shared memory to be actually deleted all processes that are attached to it 
must detach. I run `ps u` right after my application completes and none of the children it creates are running so no zombie processes, and they all detach in code the same way the parent process is detaching.

So my question is, what is going on? Why is it not deleted?

Comment: Have you tried to print out the `shmid_ds` structure using `shmctl()` with IPC_STAT as command?  You can check the `shm_nattch` inside `shmid_ds` to see if it is 0 before you do the `IPC_RMID`.  If it is not 0, it means that there are still some processes attached.

Comment: @SSC Can you set that as an answer so I can accept it? That helped me identify the problem. I was leaving a process behind, I could not find it through ps -a because it was a zombie only for a split second but it was enough to mess up my results

Comment: You probably should use POSIX shared memory (see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)) & semaphores (see [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)). SysV ones are nearly deprecated.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch will look into it for the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to  print out the `shmid_ds` structure using `shmctl()` with `IPC_STAT` as command. You can check the `shm_nattch` inside `shmid_ds` to see if it is `0` before you do the `IPC_RMID`. If it is not 0, it means that there are still some processes attached.